# How to return a FileResult and a View using one controller method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a button which saves a form by running a save function in the controller. This controller is of the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ViewModel model)
{
   Save(model);
   var newModel = new ViewModel();
   return View(Index, newModel); 
}
```

and I have a DownloadFile function of the form

```
public FileResult DownloadReceipt(int reportId)
{
   filebytes = CreateFile(reportid);
   return File(filebytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "file name");
}
```

I would like to be able to allow the user to download this file using the second function while also redirecting the user to the index using the first function. The first function gets called when a save button is clicked. Is there a convenient way to download the file onto the users computer using that button while still redirecting to the required view. Currently the download file function isn't called anywhere.

Comment: You can't return a view and a file at the same time. You can return a view with a link to download the file, or call the download via javascript.

Comment: Redirect within the `onsuccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind controller's action has a protocol called HTTP. This protocol specify for each request should be a single response. So, in answer to your question, it's not possible to respond (return) multiple pages to a single request.

But cool down, there's still hope. We could fake this behavior. There's many ways to fake it. I will show you one:

In your `Index.cshtml` you could write a call to the download page:

Index.cshtml:

```
@if((ViewBag.ReportId as int?) > 0)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "@Url.Action("DownloadReceipt", new { reportId = ViewBag.ReportId })";
        window.open(url, "_blank");
    </script>
}
<!-- the rest of index code -->
```

If you put this code in your page, as soon the page loads it will altomaticaly call the second page (DownloadReceipt), without closing the atual page.

To make it work all you need to do now is set `ViewBag.ReportId` in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ViewModel model)
{
   Save(model);
   var newModel = new ViewModel();
   ViewBag.ReportId = 5; // Change 5 for some code that get report id.
   return View(Index, newModel); 
}
```

To conclude if `ViewBag.ReportId` is set the index page will altomatically call the download page as soon it loads, otherwise (if `ViewBag.ReportId` is not set) no call to download will be made.